# Cannot get value from nested json retrofit android studio

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I want to get the value from the nested json and using retrofit. The value for both LicenseCDL and LicenseVDL classes are null. How to get the data from both array? Where did I missing from the java class?

This is the Json looks like.

```
{
    "data": {
        "LicenseCDL": [
            {
                "class_code": "B2",
                "invoice_num": "W1007INV20051",
                "total": "1484.00",
                "created_at": "2020-05-18 08:56:13"
            }
        ],
        "LicenseVDL": [
            {
                "class_code": "PSV VAN",
                "invoice_num": "W1007INV20052",
                "total": "583.00",
                "created_at": "2020-05-18 10:12:13"
            }
        ]
    },
    "status": "1",
    "message": "record found."
}
```

This is LicenseClassModel

```
public class LicenseClassModel {

@SerializedName("LicenseCDL")
private List<LicenseCDL> LicenseCDL;
@SerializedName("LicenseVDL")
private List<LicenseVDL> LicenseVDL;

@SerializedName("message")
private String message;
@SerializedName("status")
private String status;

public List<LicenseClassModel.LicenseCDL> getLicenseCDL() {
    return LicenseCDL;
}

public List<LicenseClassModel.LicenseVDL> getLicenseVDL() {
    return LicenseVDL;
}

public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public static class LicenseCDL {

    @SerializedName("class_code")
    private String classCode;
    @SerializedName("data")
    private List<LicenseDataItem> data;

    public String getClassCode() {
        return classCode;
    }

    public List<LicenseDataItem> getData() {
        return data;
    }
}

public static class LicenseVDL {

    @SerializedName("class_code")
    private String classCode;
    @SerializedName("data")
    private List<LicenseDataItem> data;

    public String getClassCode() {
        return classCode;
    }

    public List<LicenseDataItem> getData() {
        return data;
    }
}
```

This is method that I want to get the value

```
 private void callLicenseApi() {
        Call<LicenseClassModel> CheckCall = apiInterface.LICENSE_CLASS_LIST_CALL(String.valueOf(UserData.getId()));
        CheckCall.enqueue(new Callback<LicenseClassModel>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<LicenseClassModel> call, @NonNull Response<LicenseClassModel> response) {
                Log.i("???","value cdl: "  + response.body().getLicenseCDL()); //output: value cdl: null 
                Log.i("???","value vdl: "  + response.body().getLicenseVDL()); //output: value cdl: null 
            }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<LicenseClassModel> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.i("???","Erorr : "  + t.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by changing the model class to this.

```
public class LicenseClassModel {

@SerializedName("data")
private LicensePerantaraan data;

@SerializedName("message")
private String message;

@SerializedName("status")
private String status;

public LicensePerantaraan getData() {
    return data;
}

public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public static class LicensePerantaraan {
    @SerializedName("LicenseCDL")
    private List<LicenseDataItem> LicenseCDL;

    @SerializedName("LicenseVDL")
    private List<LicenseDataItem> LicenseVDL;

    public List<LicenseClassModel.LicenseDataItem> getLicenseCDL() {
        return LicenseCDL;
    }

    public List<LicenseClassModel.LicenseDataItem> getLicenseVDL() {
        return LicenseVDL;
    }
}

public static class LicenseDataItem {

    @SerializedName("class_code")
    private String classCode;
    @SerializedName("invoice_num")
    private String invoiceNum;
    @SerializedName("total")
    private double total;
    @SerializedName("created_at")
    private String createdAt;

    public String getClassCode() {
        return classCode;
    }

    public String getInvoiceNum() {
        return invoiceNum;
    }

    public double getTotal() {
        return total;
    }

    public String getCreatedAt() {
        return createdAt;
    }
}
}
```

And after that I call this method in the adapter. Using the array and using method `addAll`, before using that method, clear the array 1st.

```
private void callLicenseApi() {
        licenseDataItemArrayList.clear();
        Call<LicenseClassModel> CheckCall = apiInterface.LICENSE_CLASS_LIST_CALL(String.valueOf(UserData.getId()));
        CheckCall.enqueue(new Callback<LicenseClassModel>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<LicenseClassModel> call, @NonNull Response<LicenseClassModel> response) {
                if (response.code() == 200) {
                    if (response.body() != null)
                        if (response.body().getStatus().equals("1")) {
                            if (response.body().getData().getLicenseCDL().size() != 0) {
                                licenseDataItemArrayList.addAll(response.body().getData().getLicenseCDL());
                                licenseDataItemArrayList.addAll(response.body().getData().getLicenseVDL());

                            licenseClassAdapter = new LicenseClassAdapter(con, licenseDataItemArrayList, new RecyclerViewBaseAdapter.ItemSelectedListener<LicenseClassModel.LicenseDataItem>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onItemSelected(LicenseClassModel.LicenseDataItem listItem) {

                                }
                            });
                            tvNoRecordFound.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            rv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(con));
                            rv.setAdapter(licenseClassAdapter);
                        } else {
                            rv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            tvNoRecordFound.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }

                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(con, getString(R.string.record_not_found), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        tvNoRecordFound.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(con, getString(R.string.record_not_found), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                tvNoRecordFound.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            lytProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<LicenseClassModel> call, Throwable t) {
            callAPiForLog(TAG, t.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(con, t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

LicenseCDL and LicenseVDL are inside "data" key So you need to Update the Classes

```
public class LicenseClassModel {

@SerializedName("data")
@Expose
private Data data;
@SerializedName("status")
@Expose
private String status;
@SerializedName("message")
@Expose
private String message;

public Data getData() {
return data;
}

public void setData(Data data) {
this.data = data;
}

public String getStatus() {
return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
this.status = status;
}

public String getMessage() {
return message;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
this.message = message;
}

}

public class Data {

@SerializedName("LicenseCDL")
@Expose
private List<LicenseCDL> licenseCDL = null;
@SerializedName("LicenseVDL")
@Expose
private List<LicenseVDL> licenseVDL = null;

public List<LicenseCDL> getLicenseCDL() {
return licenseCDL;
}

public void setLicenseCDL(List<LicenseCDL> licenseCDL) {
this.licenseCDL = licenseCDL;
}

public List<LicenseVDL> getLicenseVDL() {
return licenseVDL;
}

public void setLicenseVDL(List<LicenseVDL> licenseVDL) {
this.licenseVDL = licenseVDL;
}

}
```